# Filter dataframe for non date rows and blank values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, filter, slice

I have a dataframe as following:

```
    Person Type Hire Date   Original Hire Date
 0   Employee   2010-12-01  2010-12-01
 1   Employee   2011-03-13  xxx
 2   Employee               2012-01-02
 3   employee   ?           2
 4   Employee   2012-12-19  2012-12-19
 5   Employee   2013-02-07  2013-02-07
```

I need to find a way to filter this entire dataframe in a way that it returns all rows not in date or datetime format. The output expected would be:

```
    Person Type Hire Date   Original Hire Date
1    Employee   2011-03-13  xxx
2    Employee               2012-01-02
3    employee   ?           2
```

What would be the best way to do this filtering? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the date like columns then parse the columns to datetime and use `isna` + `any` to find the rows which have one or more values in non datetime format

```
cols = df.filter(like='Date')
df[cols.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce').isna().any(1)]
```

---

```
  Person Type   Hire Date Original Hire Date
1    Employee  2011-03-13                xxx
2    Employee         NaN         2012-01-02
3    employee           ?                  2
```